# unfortunately fragments has stopped

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to the android, during the new boston tutorials of the fragments I almost did what I should do but I am facing the fragments exception:

My main activity:

```
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TopSection.TopSectionListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void createMeme(String top, String bottom)
{
    pictureFragment b = (pictureFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
    b.setMemeText(top, bottom);
}
```

My TopSection fragment:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TopSection extends Fragment
{
    private static EditText topTextInput;
    private static EditText bottomTextInput;

    TopSectionListener activityCommander;

    public interface  TopSectionListener
    {
        public void createMeme(String top, String bottom);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try
        {
            activityCommander = (TopSectionListener)  activity;
        }
        catch(ClassCastException e)
        {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_frame, container, false);

        topTextInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.topTextFeild);
        bottomTextInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.bottomTextFeild);

        final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(
               new Button.OnClickListener()
               {
                   public void onClick(View v)
                   {
                       ButtonClicked(v);
                   }
               }
        );
        return view;
    }

    public void ButtonClicked(View v)
    {
        activityCommander.createMeme(topTextInput.getText().toString(), bottomTextInput.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

my PictureFragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PictureFragment extends Fragment
{
    private static TextView topText;
    private static TextView bottomText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.picture_fragment, container, false);

        topText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.topTextView);
        bottomText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bottomTextView);

        return view;
    }

    public void setMemeText(String top, String bottom)
    {
        topText.setText(top);
        bottomText.setText(bottom);
    }


}
```

Finally the log is:

```
08-11 06:04:29.594    1500-1500/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
08-11 06:04:30.094    1500-1500/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
08-11 06:04:30.094    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 408: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
08-11 06:04:30.094    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-11 06:04:30.094    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
08-11 06:04:30.094    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 430: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
08-11 06:04:30.094    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-11 06:04:30.146    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
08-11 06:04:30.146    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 371: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-11 06:04:30.146    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-11 06:04:30.146    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
08-11 06:04:30.146    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 373: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-11 06:04:30.146    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-11 06:04:31.170    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 164K, 8% free 3178K/3424K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
08-11 06:04:31.170    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 127844364-byte allocation
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 8% free 3169K/3424K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 127844364-byte allocation.
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xa4d32bd8 self=0xb9498eb0
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ | sysTid=1500 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1216720832
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ | state=R schedstat=( 1259106028 86198384 90 ) utm=108 stm=17 core=1
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3484)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:464)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:236)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.example.yahya.fragments.pictureFragment.onCreateView(pictureFragment.java:20)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1116)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1218)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2170)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:842)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:34)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:830)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.example.yahya.fragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
08-11 06:04:31.178    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-11 06:04:31.182    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-11 06:04:31.182    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
08-11 06:04:31.182    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
08-11 06:04:31.182    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-11 06:04:31.182    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-11 06:04:31.182    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-11 06:04:31.182    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-11 06:04:31.182    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
08-11 06:04:31.182    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 06:04:31.182    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-11 06:04:31.182    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-11 06:04:31.182    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-11 06:04:31.182    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 06:04:31.182    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments I/dalvikvm﹕ [ 08-11 06:04:31.182  1500: 1500 D/skia     ]
    --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
08-11 06:04:31.182    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-11 06:04:31.186    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d31b20)
08-11 06:04:31.186    1500-1500/com.example.yahya.fragments E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.yahya.fragments, PID: 1500
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yahya.fragments/com.example.yahya.fragments.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.yahya.fragments.pictureFragment.onCreateView(pictureFragment.java:20)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1116)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1218)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2170)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:842)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:34)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:830)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.yahya.fragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.yahya.fragments.pictureFragment.onCreateView(pictureFragment.java:20)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1116)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1218)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2170)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:842)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:34)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:830)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.yahya.fragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.ja
```

The manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.yahya.fragments" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build.gradle (the fragments):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

build.gradle (module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yahya.fragments"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you already look at the '`Caused by`' part of the exception? And can you show the XML file?

Comment: please post activity_main.

Comment: Give me your Email to send you Basic Working Fragment I Created then you can Edit for your Purpose

Comment: ya_ha_na@ieee.org, Thanks

Comment: Sorry keeps Bouncing back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer myself:

One of the reasons that causes the following exception is the case that we have a large image (even in terms of MB) in the layout and the VM cannot load it. By removing that or even making it smaller in size the exception will be vanished.

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

Change 
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

To 
import android.support.v7.app.Fragment;

In your fragments

Comment: I tried to do that but when I am changing the 4 to 7 it generates an error saying that "Cannot resolve symbol Fragment"

Comment: Read this: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html and does this @Nullable ViewGroup container do?

Comment: thanks, I read that, however I already had installed that libraries and repositories. Also I cant understand your "@Nullable ViewGroup container do?".

Comment: You have it in your onCreateView Method of the Fragment

Comment: it was in the tutorial that I used

Comment: OK try and remove that and also in your Activity class since you have V4 support library extends FragmentActivity instead of ActionBarActivity. Finally change the V7 in Activity class to V4 support Library and let's see how it went.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the v7 to v4 in the Activity class but it again generated error for the fragments in that class.

Comment: Post your Gradle and Manifest File please

Comment: Roger that! I have added!

Comment: Your App gradle should be under your app/build.gradle